# Creating just one Contour line based on one spot in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, contour

The project I'm working on contains a map with different spots. Each spot has the water level [m] as an atribute. Now, I would like to create Contour lines in some spots. I know, how it works to create Contour lines with a certain distance between. But how can I create Contur lines for just some certain spots?

Answer (score 2):

Try the ["Contour plugin"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) that includes the *Use selected points only* option, see image below.

[image: window]

---

**References:**

- [Geodose | How to Create Contour Lines in QGIS](https://www.geodose.com/2018/05/how-to-create-contour-lines-in-qgis.html)
- [Nathan Woodrow  | Generating contour lines in QGIS](https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/generating-contour-lines-in-qgis/)